# How to run a python script by using cron in a docker container

Tags: python, docker, cron

I have a python code that contains a dockerfile like this:

```
FROM python:3.8.3 AS base

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install software-properties-common cron vim
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
RUN pip3 install pandas
RUN pip3 install sklearn
RUN pip3 install SQLAlchemy
RUN pip3 install ConfigParser
RUN pip3 install psycopg2
RUN pip3 install numpy
RUN pip3 install xgboost
RUN pip3 install xlrd
RUN pip3 install matplotlib

FROM base AS publish

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
RUN (crontab -l ; echo "* * * * * python /app/main.py" >> /var/log/cron.log") | crontab
CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

I want to execute my main.py python script in every minute, but my main.py is not running when i build and run the docker container. I have found some solutions on this site but those solutions did not work for me. What should i write to execute my main.py python script?

Comment: maybe you can to create loop in your main.py file with a sleep of a minute so it will run every minute?

Comment: Is there any reason that you don't schedule the cron on your host directly and run the container: `docker run ...` as a command in your crontab ?